# Failed to import "HttpStatusException" when upgrading to Vert.x 4.2.0

Tags: java, vert.x, http-status-codes

I just tried upgrading a Vert.x project which was originally written in version 4.0.3 to 4.2.0, and I stumbled on an error where I could not import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.HttpStatusException.

I can't seem to find any documentation regarding this issue and was wondering if there would be a fix to this.

The part that hinders my build is as follows.

```
public void failureHandler(RoutingContext context) {
int statusCode = context.statusCode();
String errorMessage;
if (context.failure() instanceof HttpStatusException) {
  errorMessage = context.failure().getMessage();
} else {
  errorMessage = context.failure().getMessage();
}
log.error("fail: {}", errorMessage);
JsonObject errInfo = new JsonObject().put("result", "FAIL").put("msg", errorMessage).put("data", new JsonObject());

context.response()
  .setStatusCode(statusCode)
  .putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
  .end(errInfo.encodePrettily());}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is strange. [Searching on Central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=fc:io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.HttpStatusException%20g:io.vertx) for `fc:io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.HttpStatusException g:io.vertx`, it looks like `HttpStatusException` *was* dropped from `vertx-web` in 4.1 and not moved to another dependency.

Projects that use Semantic Versioning should not have breaking changes of this sort except at a major version, but it appears Vert.x does not use that set of rules. [The class was moved to a different namespace](https://github.com/vert-x3/wiki/wiki/4.1.0-Deprecations-and-breaking-changes) because despite the fact that it was visible, the previous namespace was considered "internal".

Comment: Vert.x tries to follow semantic versioning, but note that we also have an “agreement” that changes to `impl` packages do not need to follow this rule. In 4.1, given that many users were using the `impl` class, we decided that it would be better to make it “public” hence the break.

Comment: sadly, openapi-generator-cli will still use the exception from the impl package